# Core data not being updated after managedContext.save but no errors thrown

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm trying to update an already saved entry in Core data, objectContext isn't nil neither is the managedObject. The new values get set to the managedObject with said Id. No errors are thrown when calling managedContext.save() but no changes are reflected in the coreData

I have tried using setValue() no avail and I have searched far and wide on google and stack overflow for a similar problem and most of the time it says to say that the managedObject is nil.

```swift
    var taskName:String!
    var resultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<Tasks>!

    // MARK: - Properties
    // Manage objects and update tasks
    //var resultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<Tasks>!
    var managedContext: NSManagedObjectContext!
    var tasksArray = [NSManagedObject]()
    var fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Tasks")


func settextfields() {
        let res = resultsController.fetchedObjects!
        print(res)
        for r in res {
            if r.name == taskName {
                txt_name.text = "\(r.name ?? "Task name" )"
                txt_date.text = "\(r.date ?? "Task date")"
                segmentedBtn.selectedSegmentIndex = Int(r.priority)
            }
        }
    }

    func loadTable() {
        let request: NSFetchRequest<Tasks> = Tasks.fetchRequest()
        // Sort by date
        let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "date", ascending: true)
        request.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
        resultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: request, managedObjectContext: coreData.managedContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)

        // Fetch data
        do {
            try resultsController.performFetch()
            print("Fetch successful")
        } catch  {
            print("Error performing fetch: \(error)")
        }
    }

    @IBAction func saveEdit(_ sender: Any) {
                guard let name = txt_name.text, !name.isEmpty else {
                    return
                }

                guard let date = txt_date.text, !date.isEmpty else {
                    return
                }


        do {
            loadTable()
             let res = resultsController.fetchedObjects!
                for r in res {
                    i += 1
                    if r.name == taskName {
                        print(r)
                        guard let name = txt_name.text, !name.isEmpty else {
                            return
                        }
                        guard let date = txt_date.text, !date.isEmpty else {
                            return
                        }
                        do {
                            r.name = name
                            r.date = date
                            r.priority = Int16(segmentedBtn.selectedSegmentIndex)
                        }

                        do {
                            try managedContext.save()
                            print(managedContext, r)
                            dismiss(animated: true)
                            print("Edit Successful!")
                        } catch  {
                            print("Error saving task: \(error)")
                        }
                    }
            }

        }
```

Comment: Your code is a little odd - I presume that this view controller is showing a single item that you want to edit?  If so, you should simply pass the `Tasks` object to it, rather than the task name and then re-fetching the objects.  Even if you did want to do it that way, you could just fetch the one object you are interested in by using a predicate with the name, rather than fetching all and iterating over them.  You would also just use a fetch request rather than a `FetchedResultsController`. Where do you try to show the updated data and not see it?  In a previous view controller?

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks for the reply. Yes in the previous controller, it's not updated and its not updated when I restart the app either. The row I'm trying to edit is also coming from the previous controller and I needed to pre-populate the text fields with the info from core data so they don't load blank

Comment: Yes, but there is no need to fetch the object. Pass the object instead of the object name. Then you can just access it's properties

Comment: @paulw11 So I rewrote using predicate and it worked! Thank you so much!!! But the tableView does not update once this view is dismissed or any other and tableView.reloadData() has not effect whatsoever. I have to actually restart the app for it to show

Comment: You either need to refetch the data and reload the table in `viewDidAppear` or that is where you can use a fetched results controller; the results controller delegate methods will help you get the updated data.

Answer (score 0):

I actually rewrote the save function using predicate like the person above suggested and it worked.  Then I added a viewWillLoad to the mainViewController to reload the tableView once the entry is updated

```swift
@IBAction func saveEdit(_ sender: Any) {
        guard let name = txt_name.text, !name.isEmpty else {
            return
        }

        guard let date = txt_date.text, !date.isEmpty else {
            return
        }


        do {
            let fetchRequest:NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> = NSFetchRequest.init(entityName: "Tasks")
            fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name = %@", taskName)
            let test = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
            let obj = test[0] as! NSManagedObject

            obj.setValue(name, forKey: "name")
            obj.setValue(date, forKey: "date")
            obj.setValue(Int16(segmentedBtn.selectedSegmentIndex), forKey: "priority")


            do {
                try managedContext.save()
                dismiss(animated: true)
                print("Edit Successful!")
            } catch  {
                print("Error saving task: \(error)")
            }
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is better, but if you simply passed the task rather than the task name to your second view controller you wouldn't need to fetch it at all.

Comment: You haven't shown the code where you pass the data to the second VC, but you would declare `var task: Tasks!` instead of `var taskName: String!` and assign the `Tasks` object rather than its name.